# Scrolling down to div, while hiding first div, makes the page jump down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fadeout

I've got this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em9yycj5/10/)
The problem is, when I fade out the first div, the page jumps down - so the scrolling is conflicting with the fade out.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('html, body')
      .css({
        'overflow': 'auto'
      })
      .animate({
        scrollTop: $('.second').offset().top
      }, 1500);
    }, 2000);
    return false;
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
      $('.first').fadeOut(0);
  }, 3400);
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/em9yycj5/10/

Comment: use `.animate({'opacity':'0'})` instead of `fadeOut` which sets property to `display:none`

Comment: Possible recent duplicate: http://tinyurl.com/oohalg6. By the way, fadeOut(0) would be the same as hide().

Comment: If i use .animate({'opacity':'0'}) there will just be an empty space on the top of the site.
Yes - i think it is kind of the same. How can i do, so it is not a click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing wasn't really working. The second timeout would have to start after the initial one has finished - or you could interrupt the animation (or both to be sure) :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('html, body')
    .css({overflow: 'auto'})
    .animate({scrollTop: $('.second').offset().top}, 1500);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.first').hide();
    $('html, body').stop().scrollTop($('.second').offset().top);
}, 3400);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/em9yycj5/16/

Not sure what is meant with 'a click function' in the comment above...